# Is it feasible NOT TO pop up the Console Window?

Tags: c, windows, mingw

When compiling this program in GCC-mingw32 and trying to run it, it always pops up a Console Window in a very short time and closes immediately.

```
int main (void)
{
    system("shutdown -s -t 60");  // Shutdown the computer in 1 minute
    return 0;
}
```

How could I modify this code in order to run it without any window pops up?

Is it feasible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your executable is being marked as using the console subsystem, which makes Windows show a console window automatically. If you change it to use the GUI subsystem, Windows won't show a console window. To tell MinGW to use the GUI subsystem, pass the `-mwindows` flag.